# Tascam microphone not recognized as an input device

Tags: drivers, sound, pulseaudio, microphone

I am an Ubuntu newbie, and not so familiar with Linux (used to work on Windows).
I have:

- a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop on my Dell machine.
- a working (tested under Windows 10) Tascam US122 MKII microphone
- A HiFimeDIY DAC

My problem is that the US122 Tascam microphone is recognized as an output device, and not as an input device.

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04e8:61b5 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd M3 Portable Hard Drive 2TB
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 152d:2351 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp.
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0951:1642 Kingston Technology DT101 G2
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0644:8021 TEAC Corp. TASCAM US-122mkII
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1852:7022 GYROCOM C&C Co., LTD 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 03f0:0317 Hewlett-Packard LaserJet 1200
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:2106 Dell Computer Corp. Dell QuietKey Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 413c:9013 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

---

```
$ arecord -l
**** Liste des Périphériques Matériels CAPTURE **** 
carte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 0: ALC3220 Analog [ALC3220 Analog]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0 
carte 1: DAC [HiFimeDIY DAC], périphérique 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
$ aplay -l
**** Liste des Périphériques Matériels PLAYBACK ****
carte 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], périphérique 0: ALC3220 Analog [ALC3220 Analog]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0 
carte 1: DAC [HiFimeDIY DAC], périphérique 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 1: DAC [HiFimeDIY DAC], périphérique 1: USB Audio [USB Audio #1]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 2: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], périphérique 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0
carte 3: MKII [US122 MKII], périphérique 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Sous-périphériques: 1/1
  Sous-périphérique #0: subdevice #0`
```

When running `pavucontrol`, I have only the choice between `Stereo Analogical Output` and `Stereo Numerical (IEC958) Output` for the the US122 Tascam microphone.

What should I do so as to have `pavucontrol` recognize the microphone as an input device?

Comment: try command `amixer -c 3` too